# Does Windows need a 3rd party antivirus program?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

My Windows 7 is alerting me to "Find an antivirus program online - Windows did not find an antivirus program on this computer."

Do I really need such a program, or Windows is good enough as it is if I only visit legit sites like fb, google etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an antivirus program if you go ANYWHERE on the net.

I recommend Microsoft Security Essentials as your basic AV and Malwarebytes for weekly or so scans. Both are free.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/products/security-essentials

http://www.malwarebytes.org/

Comment: "You need an antivirus program if you go ANYWHERE on the net." This cannot be emphasized enough. Just because you go to "legit" sites, like Facebook, it doesn't mean that the ad networks or a hacker can't inject malicious code into it, or someone might plug in a USB drive into your computer that is unknowingly embedded with a virus.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only basic level protection for your system then there is no need to download any other 3rd party antivirus software in your system.

For a more advanced level of protection you can go for some free version of Antivirus software like Immunet, Avast or Avira. They usually do not effect performance very much, and they're free.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking one does not NEED antivirus/firewall software but it is highly advisable to do so to protect your computer from threats like viruses and various other problems, windows does have it's own "anti malware/firewall" software but take it from me, they usually will cause you more problems then solve/prevent them as a update to windows defender recently came to close to putting my computer into the point of no return.

Comment: Microsoft Security Essentials is pretty good and (from what I've seen) has gotten the "geek stamp of approval", so to speak. Windows Defender never gave me issues, until I got hit by that zero-day Java exploit which ended up preventing Windows from booting at all (I was able to find in the logs evidence that it corrupted Defender's kernel drivers).

Comment: @sidran32 - You shouldn't blame Defender for that though.  Because it could have corrupted any security software's drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound True. I wouldn't. And it was in fact a multitude of issues preventing Windows to boot, but that was one of them.

Answer (score -3):

Regardless of "legit sites like Facebook", there is still a possibility that you *can* catch malware through one of these reputable sites. Social networks are the worst for having rogue viruses that go undetected for a while, mainly because users don't know that the virus is on their system.

However, even with antivirus -- not all viruses are caught right away. So, it's really based on personal choice.

I never used antivirus on Windows when I was gaming. However, I also ran a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows, with Ubuntu being my primary operating system. So there was never any sensitive data being entered into the Windows system, and therefore nothing to really worry about.

Again, it's all about personal choice. Some people decide to get antivirus, some people like to take their chances.

Comment: Some protection is better than no protection at all. You can get away with no antivirus software on Windows for a while (I did), but at that point you are playing with fire.

Comment: Again, it's all about personal preference. I enjoy playing with fire.

Comment: Well, I do too. I've intentionally infected my computer (or came close) just out of curiosity, too. I just don't like to pretend that it's a valid thing to do for most people. :)

Comment: ...no sensitive data... means it might not be worth a bother to you. However if your computers joins a bot net is is a bother to *us*.

Comment: @sidran32 No one is "pretending" that it is the valid thing to do. This was a legitimate answer to a legitimate question. No, you do not *need* antivirus. It's *recommended*. There's a difference between a *necessity* and a *recommendation*.

Comment: @Hennes If my computer were to join the botnet when I had my dual boot, it wouldn't have been a very effective botnet since I was in Ubuntu most of the time. I don't even have Windows on dual boot anymore, so it's not a problem for anyone.

Comment: @Sly I know. I was only trying to stress its *importance*. Because for many users (such as the one who asked the question), I would stress it as a *necessity* whereas for users like you or me, it would only be a *recommendation*.

Comment: @sidran32 Importance? Tell me how many times you've seen antivirus for Linux being mass produced in a software store. Not a downloadable version from the product's website, but an actual hard disk copy. Linux is vulnerable to viruses, too, especially when it comes to the Java drive-by downloads (which is why I refuse to install the Java plugin for any browser). The *importance* of antivirus has been set by the antivirus manufacturers themselves, and then passed onto the consumer to make them feel that they may get a virus if they aren't using their product.

Comment: @sidran32 When, in reality, not all antivirus products can even stop the simplest of viruses with polymorphic or metamorphic code.

Comment: @Sly Weren't we talking about Windows? Windows *is **very*** susceptible to viruses/malware/worms/trojans, and antivirus is crucial. Its need isn't manufactured, but practical. On Linux, that is irrelevant to the question posed. Of course no antivirus package is 100% foolproof, but that goes back to what I said before: **Some protection is better than no protection at all.**

Comment: @sidran32 All I have left to say: If government funded antivirus can't even protect government systems, how do you expect that antivirus will ever be able to protect the end user with complete confidence? If the protection fails, it's just like not having any in the first place. So what's the point? In the end, like this whole answer was about to start with, it's about *personal preference*. I'm not sure how that was even debatable, because it's not like I'm going to stick a gun to the OP's head and make them install an antivirus program.

Comment: I'm reminded of this (slightly NSFW): http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2747#comic

Comment: @HarryJohnston rofl.